# How can I make it possible to close an app by double pressing the back button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When you press the back button, you can go to the previous page in the webview. Additionally, we would like to add that when you double-press back, the app will close.

https://pub.dev/packages/double_back_to_close_app

I think I can use this, but I don't know how to apply both functions at the same time.

This is the code I created.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


final uri = Uri.parse('https://google.com');

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
      onPageFinished: (String url){
        print(url);
      }
    ))
    ..loadRequest(uri);

  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return PopScope(
      canPop: /* BOOL VALUE THAT CHECK IF ITS OK TO CLOSE APP OR NOT , YOU MAY PASS FALSE:)*/ false ,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
        //FUNCTION THAT CALL WHEN EVER THE BACK CLICKED :)
        controller?.goBack();
      },
      child: Scaffold(

        floatingActionButton: Container(
          height: 40.0,
          width: 40.0,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () => controller?.goBack(),
              backgroundColor:  Colors.grey.shade200,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        body: SafeArea(
          child : WebViewWidget(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `currentPress` variable above the build method like this:

```dart
DateTime? currentPress;
```

and use `PopScope` to handle the backpress

```dart
PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
        final now = DateTime.now();
        if (currentPress == null ||
            now.difference(currentPress!) > const Duration(seconds: 2)) {
          currentPress = now;
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text('Press back again to exit'),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            ),
          );
          return;
        } else {
          controller?.goBack();
          SystemNavigator.pop();
        }
      },
      child:Scaffold(

        floatingActionButton: Container(
          height: 40.0,
          width: 40.0,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () => controller?.goBack(),
              backgroundColor:  Colors.grey.shade200,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        body: SafeArea(
          child : WebViewWidget(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: thank you Thanks to this, I have a rough idea of ​​how to write code.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if check for onPressed call. Check if there is any route available to go then call the
**`Controller?.goBack(): SystemNavigator.pop();`**

Using a ternary check will save space and it will be easy. However, you must implement manual logic to check the available routes.

I hope It works.